# Scheduled task runs but launches batch only after minor modification

Tags: batch-file, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a problem on Windows server 2008 R2.

I scheduled a task that runs daily at fixed time using a domain account, it launches a .bat file that calls an executable passing some params.

It worked for months then without any apparent reason it stopped working: the task history shows that the task actually starts, it does not report errors but the executable does nothing.

I noticed that:

- If I am logged on remote desktop at the time of execution the task works.
- If I make a minor modification to the task (change the start time by 1 second) and save it then the task resumes normal behavior even if I am not logged.
- Other similar tasks on the same server running on the same account work properly.
- This is the second time that on the same server a scheduled task give this problem.

It seems that something in the task gets corrupted and forcing a save restores normal operation.

I already checked:

- the task runs properly if launched manually;
- permissions on .bat and exe are full control for the task account;
- The password for the account did not change;
- The "Start in" field is the .bat path;
- There are no mapped drives involved;
- The task runs with a domain account which is also machine admin, it is configured with highest privileges and of course Whether the user is logged or not.

Anyway the task worked properly for months and resumed working simply forcing a save to the task so the configuration should be ok.

Do you have any advice to detect and prevent this issue?

Comment: I'd try 1. recreating the task 2. clearing the task scheduler [registry cache](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/d24a6af9-4c42-4507-9562-fdf466c9d707/task-scheduler-corrupt-tasks?forum=itprovistadesktopui) just in case.

Comment: It could be possible that two tasks start at same time which try to access the same file. The task being a little bit faster on file access as the other one wins in this case the race on getting exclusive read/write access on file.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the only thing I can think to do is add a step of outputting a timestamp to your first task, then create a scheduled task that checks the time stamp to make sure its "current".

Out of curiosity, when this happens, does the task show that it is set when checked programmatically?

```
Dim rootFolder As TaskScheduler.ITaskFolder
Dim task As TaskScheduler.IRegisteredTask

' Create the TaskService object.
Set service = CreateObject("Schedule.Service")
service.Connect strHostname, strUsername, strDomain, strPassword

' Get the task folder that contains the tasks.
Set rootFolder = service.GetFolder("\")
Set task = rootFolder.GetTask(strNameOfTask)
WScript.Echo task.Name & " (Enabled: " & task.Enabled & ") Last Run: " & task.LastRunTime
```

Also, when you look at C:\Windows\System32\Tasks, is the XML file for the task still valid?

Without knowing exactly which part of the process broke, its tough to tell where to look for a solution.